# Why is LongDatePattern different on Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8

I just recently upgraded my machine to Win8, and some of my unit tests are failing.  I've traced this down to:

```
Win7: CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"
Win8: CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"
```

It doesn't matter which version of the .Net framework I try this under.

Is there some other global Win8 setting that has affected this?  I can't find anything about this being changed - everything indicates it should be the first pattern.

Simplest code snippet for this is to try it in PowerShell:

```
> [system.globalization.cultureinfo]::currentculture.datetimeformat.longdatepattern
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
```

The FullDateTimePattern is similarly changed: `dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt`

Comment: If your unit tests depend on a user-modifiable setting, then you've got problems.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it all correctly.  You can create a customized cultureinfo and/or datetimeformat, but when I ask for a specific one ("en-US"), it should always be the same, shouldn't it?  And where could this get changed globally?

Comment: Try comparing the regional settings for the calendar in control panel between Windows 7 and 8 to see if they are different.

Comment: Ok, I found that changing my user preferences in Windows does affect this!  Perhaps I tweaked this when installing.

Comment: I first hit this four years ago, since I use 24-hour time format.

Comment: Thanks, John - you made me dig deeper and understand what's going on.  Here's a link that explains that only the invariant culture can be considered stable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this change (which was your question) is so that the leading zero is not uselessly included. This has a positive impact on printing and storage.

Only nerds prefer the leading zero anyway ;)

Comment: Jerry, was this change documented?

Comment: No, in fact, the MSDN docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern.aspx) still show it as `Gregorian-USEnglish dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy`. Shameful.